Model.forecast() is not showin forecasting the data for the next date rather is forecasting the data for the date that is already in the training data
Problem in Python: model.forecast() Not Displaying the Next Date
I'm encountering an issue with the model.forecast() function in Python. Specifically, it is not displaying the next date, i.e., the day after the last day in my y_train which I used to train. Here are the details:
I'm working on a time-series forecasting project.
I have split my data into y_train and y_test.
I'm using AutoReg librarythe AutoReg.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

data = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index("Date")
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index).to_period('D')
# drop nan values
data.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)


series_data=data["Price"] 


cutoff = int(len(series_data)*0.9)
y_train = series_data.iloc[:cutoff]
y_test = series_data.iloc[cutoff:]

# Fit an autoregressive model to the history with lags=13
model = AutoReg(y_train, lags=13).fit()
# Forecast the next value
forecast=model.forecast()

# Displaying the forecast
print(forecast)

output:2011-09-08    2.799414 
Freq: D, dtype: float64

y_test.head(1)
output:Date2018-04-23    2.78
 

The Issue:
The library output does not include the next date after the last date in y_train. Instead, it shows
What I've Tried:

I have checked that the dates in y_train are correctly formatted and contiguous.
I tried using different values for steps in the forecast() function.

Desired Outcome:
I want the forecast to display the predicted value for the day immediately following the last day in y_train.
Additional Information:

I am using the AutoReg library.
print(forecast) should give me Date2018-04-23 instead of 2011-09-08

